# Select column and find the value from other cell

Tags: vba, excel

I needed to select column "D:D" so I did.
Then I needed to find in column value of other cell.
So what I need to do:

1. I got value in "J5" cell.
2. I need to find that value in D:D
3. I need to move one cell to right
4. I need to copy everything from cell (for example - E2)
5. Paste it in "J6"

Everything is in one sheet but the result will be used in other sheet. It's for tommorow school project. I was trying all weekend to grab answer, but I can't do it on my own and my brain is washed.

Code:

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="VA22GU1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: You're probably not going to receive help unless you post what you have tried already and ask specific questions about parts of your code that aren't working.

Comment: You should try recording a macro and then manipulating the resulting code as required. http://www.howtogeek.com/162975/geek-school-learn-how-to-use-excel-macros-to-automate-tedious-tasks/

Comment: Ok So what I was trying was everything almost from this:
`Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="VA22GU1", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate`

But to this macro ( I changed searchorder to xlByColumns). I was able to select D:D, but searching wasn't happening, nothing selected or anything. Any help how to at least select the found thing? After this I think I will be able to get rid of my problem.

Comment: Try `LookIn:=xlValues`

Comment: @Chrismas007 but how am I able to pick what im searching for? If I'll enter What:="J5" will it seek for value=J5 or value contained in cell J5? That's the point :P

Comment: `What:=Range("J5").Value`

Comment: @Chrismas007 after I entered that i got Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set and everything after selection.find on yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what I need to do:
>
> 1.I got value in "J5" cell.
>
> 2.I need to find that value in D:D
>
> 3.I need to move one cell to right
>
> 4.I need to copy everything from cell (for example - E2)
>
> 5.Paste it in "J6"

Use this:

```
'1. Variant with copy method
     Sub test()
        On Error Resume Next
        If [J5].Value <> "" Then
            Columns("D:D").Find([J5].Value).Offset(, 1).Copy [J6]
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell [J5] is empty!"
        End If
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Column [D] does not contain search criteria: " & [J5].Value
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End Sub

'2. Variant without copy method
    Sub test2()
        On Error Resume Next
        If [J5].Value <> "" Then
            [J6].Value = Columns("D:D").Find([J5].Value).Offset(, 1).Value
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell [J5] is empty!"
        End If
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Column [D] does not contain search criteria: " & [J5].Value
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: looks nice I will try it asap and give back result :)

Comment: @PrzemysławLunic Error will apear when column "D" does not contain search criteria

Answer (score 1):

Why does everyone want to bring a macro to a formula fight?

Type this in cell J6

```
=OFFSET(D1,MATCH(J5,D:D,0)-1,1,1,1)
```

Now look up the `OFFSET` and `MATCH` functions in the help.

### To elaborate on @L42 comment

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(J5,D:D,0))
```

Same result, more compact, just goes to show there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: I'd prefer `Index` over `Offset` :) Still +1 for suggesting an alternative over VBA.