# Excel INDEX/MATCH formula

Tags: excel, csv

I need to download warehouse inventory levels in a CSV, every morning, and update my website inventory CSV based on those numbers.

I've combined them into one worksheet.

Image: [http://i62.tinypic.com/1zqxd7n.png](http://i62.tinypic.com/1zqxd7n.jpg)

Column K contains the SKUs of all the items in my online store.

In column A is the list of the warehouse's SKUs, sorted to only display out-of-stock items.

I need to go down column A and see if that SKU exists in my store by looking in column K. If it's not in column K, ignore. "999999999" just means "in-stock." If it *is* in column K, write "0" in the cell one right of it, for "out-of-stock."

I'm looking for the formula for column L. So far I've tried something like =0*(INDEX(K:K,MATCH(A3,K:K,0))), but I think I've got it all wrong.

This problem is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033796/select-column-and-find-the-value-from-other-cell), but slightly different.

I would greatly appreciate your help, it would save me a LOT of time. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `INDEX` function if you aren't retrieving any values, perhaps try this formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(K:K,A3),999,0)`

That will return 999 if A3 exists in column K, otherwise 0

Comment: Barry, first of all, thanks so much for taking the time to help me out. I realized I should've been a little more clear on what I was looking for. The formula you posted would return whether or not A3 exists in column K. I need it to actually find the column A value in column K, go to that cell, and write 0 or 999 to the right of that cell (in column L).

Comment: OK, but that sounds like you are actually looking up K3 in column A, if it exists there return a 0 (because that means it's out of stock), otherwise return 999, so wouldn't that just be my formula turned around, i.e. in L3 copied down: `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,K3),0,999)`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. That's **exactly** what I was looking for! I was making it a lot more complex than it is. Now the question is: how do I skip the cells that have empty values? The columns are part of a bigger spreadsheet and the spaces need to be there. It would be difficult to skip them manually, since there are thousands of rows. [https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0577/2529/files/1.png?16527]

Comment: Try using this version: `=IF(K3="","",IF(COUNTIF(A:A,K3),0,999))` then the formula will return a blank if K3 is blank

Answer (score 1):

Eric, . The following formula should give you what you are after. I have replaced '999999' and '0' with a narrative return, as the logic (in the question) for whether or not an item is in stock appears to be the wrong way around.

Since an error would ordinarily be returned by a straight Index/Match formula, when a value cannot be found, you can build that into the formula.

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(K:K,MATCH(A3,K:K,0))),"Cannot Find in Col K","Can Find in Col K")

Comment: SnrCJ, really appreciate you taking the time to help me. I realized I should've been a little more clear on what I was looking for. The formula you posted would return whether or not A3 exists in column K. I need it to actually find the column A value in column K, go to that cell, and write 0 or 999 to the right of that cell (in column L).